# Add Transparent Background Color to Popup Page for MAUI using Community Toolkit in iOS

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit

I started working with .NET MAUI.
Installed Community Toolkit to display Popup.
Popup UI doesn't show transparent background color in iOS where as in Android it works perfectly fine.

Android:

[image: Android Popup]

iOS:

[image: iOS Popup]

Added XAML File for Popup:
Popup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mct:Popup
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="testpopup.PopupPage"
             xmlns:mct="clr-namespace:CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;assembly=CommunityToolkit.Maui"
             >
    <VerticalStackLayout BackgroundColor="Transparent">
        <Label 
            Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</mct:Popup>
```

I just modified the button on MainPage to display the popup:

```
private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ShowPopup(new PopupPage());
    }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you also add `BackgroundColor="Transparent"` to the Popup itself? In the top few lines, near `x:Class`? If that doesn't help (or is rejected by compiler as invalid property), then its probably a bug. Add issue at https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues. I also notice that the text is not centering vertically, which seems like another bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved in latest version of CommunityToolkit.Maui 4.0.0

Comment: The latest CommunityToolkit.Maui version in Nuget is 7.0.1, so is 4.0.0. correct?

Answer (score 3):

xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit" Color="Transparent"

Got it working on android

Answer (score 0):

There is the same problem in [GitHub issue](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues/499), and as the answerer said, this is normal behavior for iOS. In iOS, the hierarchy is managed by the view controller. Each page has a separate view controller. A page consists of a window, a root view, and a subview. You cannot see the layout of the previous page by setting the background color to be transparent.

For more details, you can refer to the following documents:

[User interface | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/hello-ios/hello-ios-deepdive?pivots=windows#user-interface)

[The View Controller Hierarchy | Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TheViewControllerHierarchy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH33-SW1)